# ASP.NET Core Safe To Send ID's in Models to Client?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Basic question: is it safe (normal practise) to send ID's inside a model to the client as an int or should they be encrypted strings?

Quick example:

**MemberProfileViewModel:**

```
public class MemberProfileViewModel {
   public int UserId {get;set;}   //eg UserId = 12345
   public int Age {get;set;}
   public string Username {get;set;}
   public string Nickname {get;set;}
   ...
}
```

so, in this very basic example I would be sending over to the URL "https://example.com/members/sdfjgASDVJDSasd"
the above model for the UI to render on the screen (the UserId would not be rendered but used for the post back in the controller for example).

Is it safe to pass over the UserId as an int in the model to the client? Or should the model be closer to this example:

```
public class MemberProfileViewModel {
   public string UserId {get;set;}   //eg UserId = "sdfjgASDVJDSasd"
   public int Age {get;set;}
   public string Username {get;set;}
   public string Nickname {get;set;}
   ...
}
```

The UserId is now an encrypted string that I decrypt in the controller on postback.

I always wonder which is the best practise for this kind of round trip to the client. Should ALL ID's be encrypted or is this not required? Can a knowledgeable individual get hold of the ID if it's a plain int value even tho it's not being used in the render of the page but is in the model?

Hope you can advise.

Thank you for your time.

Ro

Comment: So could you please share more details? All the data might be either encrypted or not and it depends on many factors. In some financial systems, everything could be encrypted and hashes could be sent with the request to check if it was not changed by some proxies, etc

Answer (score 0):

If your authorization system do not require for auth user id (for attacker to be able choose a password), why not?

But keep in mind:

1. You use https, so your url protected from man in the middle attack, but url will be kept in browser`s history.
2. If somebody may do harm to your system (change state, get confidential user information) using only user id - it is bad practice. Such endpoints should be protected by additional authorization system.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your system specifications.

If it is a public ID like on Facebook - you don't need any kind of encryption:
https://www.facebook.com/zuck
You can see that the "Zuck" is visible for any users and not encrypted. Furthermore, you can even try to search the users by this ID.